# Insertion and deletion in a stack using linked list

Tags: c++, pointers, data-structures, linked-list

The program is about insertion and deletion in a stack using ling lists.The push works fine but there is problem in the deletion the pop() function has some 
error. Every time i try to delete something it gives infinite error with underflow. ie. the top pointer is always null.

```
 #include<iostream>
 #include<stdlib.h>
 #include<process.h>

 using namespace std;

 struct node
 {
     int info;
     node *next;
 }*top,*save,*newptr,*ptr;

 node *create_new_node(int);
 void push(node*);
 void pop();
 void display(node*);

 int main()
  {
     top=NULL;
     int inf;
     char ch='y';
     while(ch=='y'||ch=='Y')
     {
         newptr=new node;
         cout<<"\nEnter the info to be added in the beginning of the stack\n";
         cin>>inf;
          if(newptr==NULL)
             cout<<"\nCannot create new node.ABORTING!!\n";
         else
         {
         newptr=create_new_node(inf);
         cout<<"\nPress enter to continue\n";
         system("pause");
         }
         push(newptr);
        cout<<"\nthe info has been inserted  in the stack\n";
        cout<<"\nThe stack now is\n";
        display(newptr);

        cout<<"\ndo you wish to add more elements to the stack.\nIf yes then 
 press y or else press n\n";
         cin>>ch;
         if(ch=='n'||ch=='N')
         {
             cout<<"\ndo you to delete elements from the stack\n";
             cout<,"\nIf yes then press d else press n\n";

             cin>>ch;
             if(ch=='d'||ch=='D')
             {
                 while(ch=='d'||ch=='D')
                 {
                     pop();
                     cout<<"\npress d to delete more elements y to add more 
  elements and n to exit\n";
                     cin>>ch;
                 }

             }

        }
     }
     delete(ptr);
     delete(newptr);
     delete(top);
     delete(save);
     return 0;
 }

 node* create_new_node(int n)
 {
     ptr=new node;
     ptr->info=n;
     ptr->next=NULL;
     return ptr;
 }

  void push(node *np)
  {
     if(top==NULL)
         top=np;
     else
     { 
        save=top;
        top=np;
         np->next=save;
     }
 }

 void pop()
{
     if(top==NULL)
         cout<<"underflow";
     else
     {
        ptr=top;
        top=top->next;
        delete ptr;

     }
}

void display(node *np)
{
    while(np!=NULL)
    {
        cout<<np->info<<"->";
        np=np->next;
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) what and how you can ask here.

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should [edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: You call `pop()` in an infinite loop. You prompt the user to "press d to delete more elements", but don't actually wait for the user input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple bugs in the shown code.

Your main bug:

```
while(ch=='d'||ch=='D')
{
    pop();
    cout<<"\npress d to delete more elements y to add more elements and n to exit\n";
}
```

At this point, when `ch` is `'d'` or `'D'` execution will enter the `while` loop, of course. A call to `pop()` is made, which removes the topmost element from the stack, prints a message, and repeats the `while` loop.

At this point your program will make an important discovery that `ch` is still either `'d'` or `'D'`. Nothing has changed its value. A computer program always does exactly what you tell it to do, unfortunately, instead of what you think you want it to do. No matter how hard you look here, you will never find any code here that ever changes the value of `ch`. It will remain at its current value forever. And so the `while` loop runs again. And again. And again. Nothing ever changes the value of `ch`, at this point, so you have an infinite loop.

Additionally, in your `main`:

```
    newptr=new node;
```

This pointer's value is later compared to `NULL`; and if not ... it gets completely overwritten by

```
     newptr=create_new_node(inf);
```

This accomplishes absolutely nothing, except leaking memory. This code appears to be leftover junk, and should be cleaned up after fixing the faulty `while` loop logic.

Comment: sorry I wasn't aware of the mistake I did in the while loop.Now the program runs fine.

Comment: and about the junk you are talking about...I'm new to programming and have little idea of memory leaks and all....I will be grateful if you give me some advice on how to proceed.

Comment: Your `main()` `new`ed a new pointer. The pointer was then overwritten. The pointer to the `new`ed memory was lost. The rest of the program takes steps to `delete` what's been `new`ed, instead of this instance. The memory is leaked, and lost. This matters little for this simple program, but if you expect to be a professional C++ developer some day, the sooner you learn and understand how proper memory management works, the easier it will be for you. This can't be fully explained in a brief comment on stackoverflow.com, but should be covered in your C++ book.